# angular multiple named router on empty path in lazy loaded modules

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, router, router-outlet

My issue is to make a named outlet work again after having to lazy load the module of the component

i have a minimal reproduction of the issue in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lazy-load-s6ddh7?file=app%2Fapp.component.html).

Please note this is a reproduction, a prerequisite in my project is to have
two or more empty paths that would resolve into different auxiliary routes,
since i have a "main" page with several auxiliary routes that each renders part of the page

The relevant code for main component is:

```
<nav>
  <a routerLink="/home" routerLinkActive="active">Home Link</a>
  <a routerLink="/about" routerLinkActive="active">About (lazy) link </a>
  <router-outlet name="about"></router-outlet>
</nav>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

app.routing.module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: 'home', 
    loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule),
  },
  { 
    path: '', 
    loadChildren: () => import('./comp/comp.module').then(m => m.CompModule),
  },
  { 
    path: '', 
    loadChildren: () => import('./about/about.module').then(m => m.AboutModule),
  }
];
```

comp.routing.module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { CompComponent } from './comp.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: CompComponent, outlet: 'comp' },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class CompRoutingModule { }
```

about.routing.module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AboutComponent } from './about.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: AboutComponent, outlet: 'about' },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AboutRoutingModule { }
```

note that if i put a

```
<router-outlet name="comp"></router-outlet>
```

instead of

```
<router-outlet name="about"></router-outlet>
```

it works, as if i invert the order of routes in
app.routing.module

***EDIT***

i can remove the lazy loading out of the equation refactoring the route this way

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: 'home', 
    loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule),
  },

  { 
    path: '', 
    loadChildren: () => import('./comp/comp.module').then(m => m.CompModule),
  },
  
  /*
  { 
    path: '', 
    loadChildren: () => import('./about/about.module').then(m => m.AboutModule),
  },
  */
  { 
    path: '', 
    children: [{
      path: '',
      component: AboutComponent, 
      outlet: 'about' 
    }]
  }

];
```

this way it's obvious that i somewhat can't have different children instances for the same (empty) route

thank you for any suggestion

Comment: The instead of snippet is the same as the one it replaces in the comment sir

Comment: Is the paths in Routes for about and comp are intentionally empty?

Comment: yes they are empty in my original project as well as they serve as auxiliary routes

Comment: Why do you need outlet here? Adding 'about' path to your about route in Routes solve the error

Comment: this is a reproduction of a project in which there is a "main" page with several auxiliary routes that each renders part of the page, hence why i have two or more empty paths, if i add a "about" path i lose the ability to render the component in the main page